# Java: Extending a Class File Outside the Working Directory

Tags: java, inheritance

I am new to programming, so please bear with me; I will try to make my question as clear as possible. Responses are greatly appreciated as I am struggling quite a bit with the following question...

As you'll likely know,

"Inheritance [in Java] allows the **compiled** form of classes to be modified and/or extended. If a class is available that almost satisfies your requirements, you can adjust it..." (Dos Reis, 2012)

My question:

How do you compile a .java file containing a subclass who's class that is

1. Only available as a .class file
2. Outside the current working directory

I hope this is clear, and once again apologies beforehand for lacking the expertise to phrase this question more clearly.

Comment: I'm afraid this is quite unclear (at least to me).  What problem are you actually trying to solve here?

Comment: Hi Oliver. If I'm correct, you can use -sourcepath to access .java files outside the working directory (the directory you are in when you compile,) if those .java files contain classes that you want to import, for example. What if you are compiling a .java file that contains a class that extends another class, but the extended class is only available in a .class file, and is outside the working directory?

Comment: lets say I am in /Users/cedrichill/Desktop/Projects/src/packagename, and am attempting to compile a file called SubClass.java. The class SubClass extends SuperClass, and SuperClass.class is located in /Users/cedrichill/Desktop/Projects/bin/otherpackagename

Comment: You need to set the classpath to contain the folder of your compiled classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple: to the java compiler, it doesn't matter if a class comes as source or compiled.

The only thing: a compiled class needs to be on the **class path** of the javac invocation.

Keep in mind: *any* class inherits from java.lang.Object. You do not have Object in your source path. It only exists as class file in some JAR coming with your JDK!

In other words: when the compiler finds source code, it uses that. If not, it will check the classpath given to it and search for a compiled version of the class you intend to use.